# Footers are disappearing when adding text "behind" title page

Tags: header-footer, titles, copyright

I have a "book" with a cover and several chapters and appendices. I need to add some text and images (publishers) "behind" the cover. So I tried the `\newpage` command after the title page. It worked, but after doing this all the footers from the "next section" (index, chapter, whatever) disappeared. I don't know whats wrong. I reduced the document/code to the minimum, because I thought it could be due to some package conflict. But, even with this simple example, I'm having the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my sample code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter   
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else   
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{Test}
\newpage    
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}  

\renewcommand\maketitle{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
\null\vfil
\begin{center}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%\bigskip
{\huge \LaTeX test} \\[25mm]
{\Large by} \\[25mm]
{\LARGE Me} \\
\end{center}
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}  %% COMMENT THIS LINE AND FOOTERS APPEAR AGAIN
%\strut \vfill \null
\copyright\ Me, \the\year
\null\par
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
%{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage}
}
\makeatother    

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\Blindtext\Blindtext
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Here are some images (cannt add them 'cause i don't have 10 reputation =):

In my output, if I add `\newpage`, footers from the next chapter disappear:

[image]

---

If I comment/delete `\newpage`, footers from the next chapter are there:

[image]

Comment: Hi Rose, welcome! You are defining the footer inside the `\cleardoublepage` command. Your if statements are set up so that the footer definition only happens when the current page is even. Maybe you should take the definition outside of the if statements (or even outside of the command definition?)

Comment: The fancyhdr definition should go outside of the `\cleardoublepage` definition. Also some of your `\thispagestyle` commands are useless or at the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, when I was reducing code I forgot to remove remaining useless statements. But I never thought the IF from the header/footer can have any effect (in my real document I have other setup for titles, parts, even pages, etc.). **So much thanks**, I'll check it up.

Comment: It worked!!! ^^

Taking the header/footer definition out (removing the `\ifodd`) did it. I'm just wondering _why?_ I mean, it really matters if I add a "new page" at the beginining of the document (or at any other place)? I would imagine that, adding a new page means: odd pages become even and even pages become odd... I don't know why footers disappeared with the `\ifodd` in both pages: even and odd, as shown in figure A.

Any way, again: *thanks*, I really appreciate your help. ^^

Answer (score 1):

The fancyhdr definition should go outside of the `\cleardoublepage` definition. Also some of your `\thispagestyle` commands are useless or at the wrong place.